# Optimize SSIS package for fewer queries

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, dts

I need to associate customers' order with their "level" (Silver, Gold, etc.) *when they placed the order*:

```
CRM server::CRM db::CRM table
----------
CustomerID   PreviousLevel    NewLevel    NewLevelGrantedOn

Order server::Order db::Order table
----------
OrderID     CustomerID    OrderPlacedOn
```

In an SSIS package I did this:

1. Execute SQL against Order db to extract the orders and put them in an object variable;
2. Loop through each order using "foreach container", in which I put a data flow task `select top 1 * where CustomerID = ? and LevelGrantedOn < ? order by LevelGrantedOn desc` that extract data from CRM db (both parameters come from step one), derive some columns and write the output to another table.

There are more then twenty thousand records in the order db, which means the data flow task will be executed for more than twenty thousand times. The CRM db will be queried for more than twenty thousand times, too. It takes more than an hour to do these.

Can I utilize some built-in features to speed up these (or do it in a "smart" way)? And, is an hour a long time, in the context of ETL and / or SSIS?

Comment: If you have the option, consider actually copying the results of the `OrderDB` query to a table in the `CRM` db. You might then be able to restate your CRM query so it's set-based, so you only run the one query (or a few sequential queries), instead of running your queries once for each row from `OrderDB`. And, an hour's only a long time if it's interfering with other processes, or if future growth will make it take longer until it does. A one-off process only requires enough optimization to complete successfully - a recurring process is worth spending a bit more time on.

Comment: @RDFozz no I can't write to either order or crm db.

Comment: Can you add a user-created database to the CRM server, and copy the order info into that? Or, for that matter, set up the server the `Order` DB is on as a linked server on the CRM server? As much as I like and have used SSIS packages, trying to use them to join data from two servers is simply not something it generally does quickly, in my experience.

Comment: No I have no write permission on either server. I can only "select". The only db / server I have full control is the local server where I run the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You can achieve this without using Foreach enumerator, just use one data flow task to achieve this.*

### Building the Package

*First of all, add a Data Flow Task to the control Flow*

*1. OLEDB Sources*

In the DataFlow task add an `OLEDB Source` that Read from Orders Table (the same command used in the `Execute SQL Task` *(first step in your question)*

```
Select * FROM Order
```

Also add a second `OLEDB Source` that read from customer table:

```
select * FROM CRM
```

*2. Sort*

After each OLEDB Source add a source component:

1. The First (order table) you have to select `CustomerID` and `OrderID` columns for sorting and select the sort type as ascending
2. The Second (customer table) you have to select `CustomerID` *(sort type 
   = ascending)* and `LevelGrantedOn` *(sort type 
   = descending)* columns for sorting

*3. Merge Join*

Add a merge Join component to join both sorted outputs. and select `CustomerID` column from both outputs as Join Key and select the output columns you need from both tables

*4. Conditional Split*

After merge Join add a conditional split to filter rows only that match the following expression

```
[LevelGrantedOn] < [orderdate]
```

*5. Script Component*

The final component we have to use is a script component to get only the first row for each customerID *(because both source are well sorted just grabbing the first row is similar for `Select top 1 ... ORDER BY LevelGrantedOn desc`)*

In the script component add an Output Column `OutFlag` of type `DT_BOOL` and Use the following script:

[image]

*This script will set OutFlag to True when the customerID occur for the first time (similar to `TOP 1`)*

```
    Public Class ScriptMain
        Inherits UserComponent


        Dim lstCustomerID As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)
        Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

            If lstCustomerID.Contains(Row.ID) Then

                Row.OutFlag = False
            Else

                lstCustomerID.Add(Row.ID)
                Row.OutFlag = True


            End If



        End Sub

    End Class
```

*6. Conditional Split*

Add a second Conditional Split to filter Top 1 rows:

```
[OutFlag] == True
```

*7.OLEDB Destination*

Connect the Conditional Split Output top the OLEDB Destination and map the columns.

**The Dataflow task must looks like**

[image]

Comment: The `LevelGrantedOn` variable is from order table. It is, actually, the order date. How can I still have that variable if I use oledb source?

Comment: Just edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Can you create a linked server. It is the best way to achieve your goal.

Comment: No I can't use linked server.

Comment: You can use merge join + conditionnal split to achieve that. Few minutes and i will update my answer

Comment: @Ryan check my answer update

Comment: I think both of your two answers are very informative, although the first one may not fit my situation very well. I'll try out the second one after I go back to work.

Comment: @ryan still waiting for a feedback :)

Answer (score -1):

Consider using SQL Server "Index with included columns" feature which can speed up the query performance during the data collection process.